# Why should a user be redirected to a new page after login

Tags: web-applications

Perhaps I am over thinking this, but I would like to understand the purpose of redirecting a user after the POST of their credentials to login page. For example, the POST action can submit the user's credentials, for example to something like /app/login.php, and then after authentication that login application page could load perhaps a landing page for the user without actually redirecting the user. However, is there something that happens if a user is redirected to a new page instead? It is recommended, but I have not found any explanation for it other than preventing the user from potentially reloading the page and potentially resubmitting form data. It is recommended as a security best practice and I can theorize why it might be done in that regard, but I would really like to have an answer other than "... because that is what everyone does."

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: "that login application page could load perhaps a landing page for the user" - how is that different from a redirect? And how would you do this without one?

Comment: I've written an answer but also voted to move the question to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com - It's more suited to there, I think :)

Comment: @Jonathon Bolster: I think this is very much a (web) developer's topic, and there's evidence below that not every web developer understands it.

Comment: @Oded: If you have your web views decoupled from individual asp / php / jsp files, you can display whatever view you want in code, and even without that, you can use an if to choose which markup to send. It differs from a redirect in the way the browser interacts with the server, though. The login submission (and all *actions*) should be a POST request, while all *views* should be GET requests. This way normal browser navigation (which is intended to deal with *views*) doesn't inadvertently trigger *actions*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a very quick point. When the advice is to redirect a user, it is normally using the
[Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) method. So the user isn't usually presented with a 'You are being redirected' message or something similar. The server sends the redirect in the response and the browser takes action and goes to the location given.

---

***A short example:***

Imagine you have a site with:

- A login page ( http://domain.com/login )
- A dashboard page ( http://domain.com/dashboard ).

One reason is for separation of functionality. So your login page is specifically for logging in and dashboard page is to show the user's account (or something similar).

Yup, you could just include the dashboard/other page in the login page without redirecting but then you run into another problem. If the user can access their dashboard using /login and /dashboard, what happens if they bookmark the login page? Also, if you are on a POSTed page, then if the user wants to refresh the page then the browser will probably warn them that they'll repost. From a purely usability view, this would be really annoying if I had to keep accepting just to see my News Feed on Facebook.

Each refresh on the posted page would log the user back in. If you had an audit log enabled then you'll have a load of 'Login' records just because the user wanted to refresh the news feed. Imagine if your site did something on each user login (for example, sending an email out). Just refreshing the dashboard page would send out an email each time.

---

Another reason is that lots of sites will provide a redirect URL when an unauthenticated user tries to access a restricted page. After logging in, the site redirects the user to the page they originally requested. The [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) for logging in makes this easier to do (if you've already implemented it for general logging in, then it's not much more effort to have this feature).

There are various other reasons but one of the biggest for me is that the form isn't resubmitted. Not related to just logging in, but I once had a 'Test SMS' feature on a site of mine that didn't implement the Post-Redirect-Get method. Someone sent one test message and then kept pressing refresh. Within a few minutes all of my SMS credits were used up. Yes, the person could have just pressed back and resubmitted but refresh is just easier.

Comment: Thank you very much all for the well thought out responses. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

These answers seem very much dependent on the server side implementation. After all, you can return the user a landing page from a different JSP or ASPX or whatever in response to their POST request without a browser redirect.

I believe redirecting the browser has the following advantages:

- Allows Reload and Bookmarking and Back button without That Nasty Dialog or reposting
- Combine this with the way you handle "not logged in" - go to the log in page then have it redirect to the page the user originally asked for. This allows bookmarking, deep linking, collaboration by sharing links.

I've seen this more for things like comment submissions, sites like this. I can reload the comment page to see new information without my browser warning me about reposting, and without a user who doesn't understand what that means submitting a duplicate copy of their comment.

If login has side effects then you want to avoid unnecessary logins.

Comment: To add to your last sentence, generally POST requests are for *actions* (login being one example). Maybe duplicates don't have bad symptoms if your action is idempotent, but the correct behavior for an application is to take an action only when the user indicates that action through the UI. Not when they're trying to refresh a page. (+1 btw)

Comment: Thank you very much all for the well thought out responses. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are various other reasons but the reason I would always transfer the user to a new landing page after processing the login is to ensure my pages only contain functionality which is relevant to them.  Why should a page which deals with login also be concerned with displaying a home page, which will typically need to get data from one place or another?  It shouldn't, that functionality should be separated out.

If you try to stick unrelated functionality into the same page in your application you're going to run in to trouble fairly quickly and will soon have spaghetti code which is difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

> than preventing the user from potentially reloading the page and
>   potentially resubmitting form data.

The user can still hit the back button to return and resubmit the post. The only reason is to separate the page purposes. The login page only logs you in and nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

@jmcdev: There's no particular reason. You can leave the user on the same login page, if you wanted to. Usually one redirects a user to a landing page when there are other options that the user won't be able to see in the login page because they are meant to be protected.

For example, you only require a user to authenticate when he's ready to do a checkout so you can get his personal information.